# Reflection - Method caching for multiple subclasses

Tags: java, caching, reflection

I've got one `abstract` class which is extended by multiple concrete classes.
The abstract class initialization block fetch all the methods of the current class hierarchy searching for particular annotated methods.

```
ConcreteClass2 > ConcreteClass1 > AbstractClass
OtherConcrete1 > AbstractClass
```

---

```
{
   ...

   final List<Method> methods = new ArrayList<>(16);
   Clazz<?> clazz = getClass();

   while (clazz != Object.class) {
      for (final Method method : clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
         if (method.isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation.class)) {
            methods.add(method);
         }
      }

      clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
   }

   METHODS.put(getClass(), methods);

   ...
}
```

These concrete classes are instantiated in a web/application server and are used  inside `Servlet`s.

As per se `Reflection` is not the fastest, and as I do not want to repeat the scan every time a concrete type is instantiated (`new`), what is the best strategy to cache the annotated `Method`'s.

I'm actually using `ConcurrentHashMap` as `<Class<? extends AbstractClass>, List<Method>>`, and In the initialization block I check if the `Map` already contains an entry for the uppermost concrete type.

However I do not think this is the best way to handle it. And by the way, I cannot have external dependencies.

Comment: After the web app starts, perhaps a one-time scan (similar to Spring) for your annotation.

Comment: @AndrewS I cannot modify the application startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Java 8, use `computeIfAbsent` to avoid recomputing the set of methods with annotations:

```
private static final ConcurrentMap<Class<?>,List<Method>> METHODS = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
...
Clazz<?> clazz = getClass();
METHODS.computeIfAbsent(clazz, c -> findMethods(c));
...
private static List<Method> findMethods(Class<?> clazz) {
    final List<Method> methods = new ArrayList<>(16);
    while (clazz != Object.class) {
        for (final Method method : clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            if (method.isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation.class)) {
                methods.add(method);
            }
        }
        clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
    }
    return methods;
}
```

This would cache methods per class, and avoid recomputing `List<Method>` for the same class.

Comment: Unfortunately the codebase is over JDK 1.6. I have pretty big contraints.

Comment: If you have Guava, you can use an unbounded `Cache` instead.